# Parsing an array of string to MVC method

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Im trying to parse a simple array of guids/strings to json
the json is used as a parameter on a post call to my controller.

I have been trying a lot of different things but i simply cant make the controller method see my List.

The array is built from checkbox values:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

and looks alright.
then i try to convert it to JSON

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Summarize').click(function () {
        var arrayJson = {};
        for (i in selected) {
            arrayJson[i] = selected[i];
        }
        var json = {
            SelectedQuantities: arrayJson
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/MVC/Physical/SelectQuantities/@Model.TopID",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.status == 200)
                    location.replace = "/MVC/Physical/QuantitySummaryView/@Model.TopID"
                else {
                    //Handle error
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

My controller method looks as following:

```
public ActionResult QuantitySummaryView(Guid id, List<String> SelectedQuantities)
```

But the list is always null. I figured it was because the JSON list doesnt contain the array of GUIDs directly underneath it.

Can you help me get it nudged in place?

JSON (as seen by Chromes  dev tools) looks as following:

```
{
"SelectedQuantities": {
    "0": "707c40bd-4434-41ed-80fd-4ac541a81e85",
    "1": "a8d78a4b-b107-4e1c-97b5-5d8abf530ba8",
    "2": "a19226cc-9b22-4174-97e3-bb003d4b2746"
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp.net, but your controller expect to get a List in parameter, but your jQuery post a Json String...not a List.  i would try changing the parameter List<String> SelectedQuantities to String SelectedQuantities and convert the json String to a LIst in your controller.  Hope that help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are serializing one too many times, and you have one too many layers.  Try this:

I removed one of the SelectedQuantities, and change the ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Summarize').click(function () {
        var arrayJson = {};
        for (i in selected) {
            arrayJson[i] = selected[i];
        }

        var json = {
            SelectedQuantities: arrayJson
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/MVC/Physical/QuantitySummaryView/@Model.TopID",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    });
});
```

Also, try Firebug, it will show you want was passed to the server, so you can make sure the json created and passed is correct.

Comment: Tried implementing this but it still complains about the list being null.
I updated my original question with the edited code pr your example. Would you mind taking a look at it again?

Comment: bonus info. I can make it work by using $.post and not stringify'ing it. But it doesnt work through AJAX neither with or without stringify.
$.post("/MVC/Physical/SelectQuantities/@Model.TopID", json,
                    function (data) {
                        location.href = "/MVC/Physical/QuantitySummaryView/@Model.TopID"
                    }
                );

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stringify the json nor do you need to add the dual `SelectedQuantities`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Summarize').click(function () {
        var arrayJson = {};
        for (var i in selected) {
            arrayJson[i] = selected[i];
        }

        var json = {
            SelectedQuantities: arrayJson
        };
        //json = JSON.stringify(json);
        $.post("/Home/QuantitySummaryView/@Model.TopID", json, true);
    });
});
```

However, based on your code you'll only get the number of items checked (all of them equal to "on") You don't have any code to pass the name of the item that was checked, nor do you pass the ones that are not checked. So you might have to change your code anyway to handle name/value pairs.

Comment: Thank you for this :) Such a small but significant error.
I dont need the names, all i need are the guids.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

A model which contains a collection of GUIDs:

```
public class GuidModel
{
    public GuidModel()
    {
        Guids = new List<Guid>();

        Guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        Guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        Guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        Guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        Guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    public IList<Guid> Guids { get; set; }
}
```

The checkboxes are rendered by the view:

```
<% var index = 1; %>
    <% foreach(var guid in Model.Guids) { %>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%= guid %>" name="guid<%= index %>" />
     <%: guid %>
     <br />
     <% index++; %>
<% } %>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Summarize" id="Summarize" />
```

The JavaScript / jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected = [];

    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $('#Summarize').click(function () {
        var arrayJson = {};
        for (i in selected) {
            arrayJson[i] = selected[i];
        }

        var json = {
            SelectedQuantities: arrayJson
        };
        json = JSON.stringify(json);

        $.post("/Home/QuantitySummaryView?data=" + json);
    });
</script>
```

The action method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuantitySummaryView(string data)
{
    // Deserialize the string containing JSON serialized data
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();    
    //...
}
```